# Store password for network share that is connected via dns name

Tags: windows, networking, dns, network-shares

I am using Windows 8.1 as client and a cheap NAS-System (from fantec). The NAS offers an smb-share which I use as network share. It is no problem to connect the network share, but even if I put the checkmark for "Remember my credentials" - after a reboot or relogon - windows asks me to enter my password again (the username is allready filled out correctly). All this happens only if I connect the network share via its DNS name (I run a dnsmasq on my local router). If I connect it via IP everything is fine. But I really don't want to use the IP, because I need to connect to multiple shares on the same NAS, which is only possible with different names.

I hope someone has an idea. A batchfile as logon script would only be a temporal work around, because the passwords should not easyly be visible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit `WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to set association between IP and name.

Comment: Hmm, no it didn't help, it's the same behaviour.